# iPhone UIDatePicker setMaximumDate

Tags: iphone, datepicker, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to build a datepicker which has today as a minimum date and 1 Feb 2011 as Maximum date.

I have set the minimum date as followed

```
[picker setMinimumDate: [NSDate date]];
```

and this works just fine but the MaximumDate does not seem to be correct.

```
[picker setMaximumDate: [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"11/02/01"]];
```

How do I set the maximum date correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer. Thanks anyway for your help.

```
[picker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

NSDateFormatter* formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter1 setLenient:YES];
[formatter1 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter1 setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSString* dateString = @"February 1 2011 10:00am";
NSDate* maxDate = [formatter1 dateFromString:dateString];

[picker setMinimumDate: [NSDate date]];
[picker setMaximumDate: maxDate];
```

Comment: Hey @Matthew, set it as the correct answer so! Click on the check mark.

Comment: it wont let me do that for another 2 days - so I will do it then :D

Answer (score 3):

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
        NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
        NSDateComponents *comps = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
        [comps setYear:0];
        NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
        [comps setYear:-5];
        NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];

        [datePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
        [datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

hear showing date current date to minDate and five year(back) to maxDate
it's show only five year.....

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it in Interface Builder's palette. I think if you press "Command-1" it will switch to a tab in the palette that allows you to set the Maximum date for the picker.