# Setting maximum date as current date in uidatepicker

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIDatePicker, setting maximum and minimum dates based on todays date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064864/uidatepicker-setting-maximum-and-minimum-dates-based-on-todays-date)

I have tried allot but not able to give any range to uidatepicker, specifically maximum range as current date. No matter what I do the picker always shows all the values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also [iPhone UIDatePicker setMaximumDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596987/iphone-uidatepicker-setmaximumdate)

Answer (score 2):

here's a possible answer for setting the datepicker for 30 years before and 30 years after.

you can change the values for that..

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] 
initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[comps setYear:30];
NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
[comps setYear:-30];
NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];

[datePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

hope this helps..

Comment: And you ... you should post your source instead of copy and past http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064864/uidatepicker-setting-maximum-and-minimum-dates-based-on-todays-date

Answer (score 1):

Hum you really should read the documentation.
UIDatePicker have two properties : maximumDate and minimumDate ... Both of them are NSDate object. Enjoy !